# only display an image if it's present in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a blog page on my website and some posts have images and some don't. If there wasn't an image it was showing an error so I changed the code to only show if an image is present

```
.post_body
    = @post.body.html_safe
    - if @post.image
      = filepicker_image_tag @post.image, w: 208, h: 208, fit: 'clip'
```

On my localhost, this worked well to solve the problem and nothing was displayed if I hadn't added an image to the post. But when I push it to heroku, my code changes haven't made any difference. If there is no image on the post it shows a broken image icon.

Does anyone know why this would be fine in localhost but not online?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add condition, like this

```
filepicker_image_tag @post.image, w: 208, h: 208, fit: 'clip' unless @post.image.blank?
```

or

```
.post_body
    = @post.body.html_safe
    - if @post.image.present?
      = filepicker_image_tag @post.image, w: 208, h: 208, fit: 'clip'
```

Comment: thank you, that worked! Can you explain why it wasn't enough just to say 'if post.image'?